# Can My ISP's Assigning me a New IP Explain Poor Performance on my Home Network?

Tags: router, performance, home-networking, dhcp, isp

I have observed numerous times that poor performance on my home network, which is infrequent and characterized by slow transfer rates (especially over wireless), is resolved by rebooting the router. Further, after the bounce, the router exhibits a new external IP. Is the assignment of a new IP from my ISP, or my router's apparent inability to accept it without a reboot, responsible for the performance issues?

I seldom have these issues under any other circumstance.

ISP: Centurylink (DSL)

Modem: Zyxel pk5001z (operating in bridge mode)

Router: ASUS RT-N56U

Comment: Performance problems within your intranet have nothing to do with your ISP.

Comment: No is the short answer

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: Slow transfer rates to/from the Internet or within your network? If it were an ISP issue, it would only affect Internet speed, on wireless and wired connections alike.

Comment: Good point--I should have stated that all performance issues are to/from the Internet. Intranet connectivity is fine.

Comment: @Gene - Except you said they were not fine.  You said you had slow transfers over wireless.  I took that has your intranet transfers.

Answer (score 3):

No, but there can be numerous causes for low transfer rates on your local network. In many cases, the router is at fault and if so, rebooting it may (temporarily) solve the problem. The assignment of a new IP address is an unrelated side-effect of rebooting.